# Rip DVDs in highest possible quality on Windows 8.1

Tags: video, audio, optical-media, ripping, mkv

I have a bunch of concert DVDs that I'd like to rip to the highest quality format possible. I'm looking for some software (ideally free) that will let me do this. I want to be able to keep the chapter markers and have the ability to name the chapters. I'm thinking I'd need to rip to MKV to get the highest quality and keep the chapters like this.

I know I could easily search for "Free DVD ripping" but that just gives me a ton of results that feel spammy. That's why I'm looking for recommendations here. I'm on Windows 8.1.

Thank you!

Edit: I think VLC can do what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. When I try the "convert/save" menu option and select my DVD drive, and my quality/output settings and start the process it seems as though it is doing something. My DVD drive ramps up and it definitely is trying to convert the media. It creates an MKV output file of a good size (~5GB for a 2 hour video) but when I open the file it does not play at all.

I noticed the VLC told me the MKV muxer is not included with VLC, maybe this is my problem. How do I get the muxer? I tried searching around but could only find other programs, no "muxer" or codec file that I was expecting.

Comment: Handbrake is what I personally use - free, open-source, works great, and does everything you listed.

Comment: @JonasCz Thanks! Just tried it out and it works great! Since these are concert DVDs I do want to make sure I'm getting the best possible audio out of them. If you have any pointers let me know! Right now I'm using the default AAC codec and turning the bitrate up to 448.

Comment: IIRC, Handbrake also lets you use FLAC, which would give you completely lossless audio. But AAC at 448kbps is already pretty much lossless - it would be pretty much impossible to hear the difference.

Comment: @JonasCz: Please make that an answer

Comment: FYI: If you want/need the highest possible quality (and don't care about the file size), i wouldn't convert anything and copy the original video & sound track and mux them into a `.mkv`. - the reason is called [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss)... FLAC is an exception because its lossless.